# What Family of Groups is Similar to Semidihedral?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I was excited to find that the semidihedral group of order 16 matches what I'm looking for as a model. The larger order semidihedral groups unfortunately do not generalize the relations I'm looking for:

$$G_{2^{2n}} = \langle a, x \ |\ a^{2^{n+1}}=e\ ,\  x^{2^{n-1}}=e\ ,\ xax^{-1}=a^{3}\rangle$$

Edit: In case that's hard to read supers on supers, I'm looking for groups that are generated by $\langle a,x \rangle$ with $$\left\vert a \right\vert = 2^{n+1}, \left\vert x \right\vert=2^{n-1}, xa=a^3x$$

(with $n\geq 2$). For $n=2$, [$G_{16}=SD_{16}$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Semidihedral_group:SD16). But for larger $n$ the semidihedral groups do not have the same structure. The key is that the order of $a$ and $x$ should both double for each increment in $n$, but the relation $xa=a^3x$ is the same for all $n$. I'm not sure if the groups are well-studied and well-classified as a family.

I'm not an expert in group theory, but I'd like to study these groups and learn as much as I can about group theory along the way. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: The next example in your family (with $n=3$) has order $64$ and SmallGroup Id <64, 46>. Many names are given here:
https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/61/C8.Q8.html
None of them are particularly interesting, so these might not be particularly studied. On the other hand, the structure of your groups is not very complicated, so if you have particular questions, people might be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you, it is in fact Group <64,46>! It's the [Semidirect Product of $Z_{16}$ and $Z_4$ via Cube Map](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Semidirect_product_of_Z16_and_Z4_via_cube_map) ... I'm not sure why the presentation in the link you posted has three generators? I don't see how it can be isomorphic to a group with two generators. I'm also curious why you say they're 'not interesting'? I guess if I write an interesting paper about semidirect products of $Z_{2^n}$ with $Z_{2^{n+2}}$ via cube map I can publish it, lol